# Single page authorization bypass issue on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, authentication, web-config, authorization

I have an ASP web application, which requires authorisation in order to access the site resources.

I have 2 roles used to configure access, administrator and user.

I have a web.config file in each folder and I am using a sitemap.

What I would like to do, is bypass all security and allow anonymous access to a single page (ExpiringContracts.aspx)

Here is a copy of my web.config that is stored in the root folder.

```
    <system.web> 
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization> 
    <siteMap enabled ="true" defaultProvider="SiteMap">
      <providers>
        <add name="SiteMap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Web.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
  </system.web>

  <location path="ExpiringSupplier.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/> 
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

As you can see above I have added a location path exception for ExpiringSupplier.aspx, however whenever I visit this page, the application tries to redirect to the login page at https://localhost:44338/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fExpiringSupplier.aspx

Here is my sitemap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
 <siteMapNode url="" title="Home" description="" roles ="*">
   <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home" description="Home Page" roles="*" />

   <siteMapNode url="javascript:;" title="Billing" description="Billing" roles ="Administrator">
     <siteMapNode url ="~/Billing/Invoicing.aspx" title="Invoicing" description="Invoicing">
     </siteMapNode>
     <siteMapNode url ="~/Billing/Reocurring.aspx" title="Reocurring Invoices" description="Reocurring Invoices">
     </siteMapNode>
   </siteMapNode>

   <siteMapNode url="javascript:;;" title="Contracts" description="Contracts" roles ="Administrator">
    <siteMapNode url ="~/Contracts/Contracts.aspx" title="Contracts" description="Contracts">
     </siteMapNode>
   </siteMapNode>

   <siteMapNode url="javascript:;;;" title="Reference Data" description="Reference Data" roles ="Administrator">
      <siteMapNode url ="~/ReferenceData/Customers.aspx" title="Customers" description="Customers">
       </siteMapNode>
       <siteMapNode url ="~/ReferenceData/Suppliers.aspx" title="Suppliers" description="Suppliers">
       </siteMapNode>
   </siteMapNode>

   <siteMapNode url="javascript:;;;;" title="Backup" description="Backup" roles ="Administrator">
     <siteMapNode url ="~/Backup/Backup.aspx" title="Backup" description="Backup">
     </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
 </siteMapNode>  
</siteMap>
```

How can I stop this from redirecting and allow anonymous access to this single page?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly allowing anonymous users in your `<location path="ExpiringSupplier.aspx">` element?  I.e. `<allow users="?"/>` instead of / in addition to `<allow users="*"/>`.

Comment: @Joe Yeah, I tried that and it does the same and redirects to the login page

Comment: Try putting the location element above the auth. Not sure if it works in this case but reading `deny` first, might halt the process before it reaches any `allow`s.

Comment: Did some more reading and it *shouldn't* make a difference.